# Maven timestamp and time properties

Tags: maven, build

I would like to know if there is a way in maven to add a time property dependent on the current timestamp. For example I would like to have a property with the time now plus one hour. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `build-helper-maven-plugin`'s `timestamp-property` goal. Check [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/timestamp-property-mojo.html).